# Convert mixed data into string numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have this array:

```
z = np.array(['43', '65', '41', '47', '46', '73', '99', '52', '56', '23', '07',
       'C3', '49', '62', '54', 'A1', '88', '70', '42', 74.0, 20.0, 21.0,
       4, 62, 2, 3, 49, 79, '13', 'F4', 'A9', '20', '19', 19.0, 23.0,
       70.0, 83, 61, 80, 81, 66, 82, 63, '09', '06', 'F8'], dtype=object)
```

In this array, we have int, str and float in one array. I want to convert all of them into string but float values have to be integer and the values such as '07', '09', etc also turn into '7', '9'. The desire result I want is:

```
z = np.array(['43', '65', '41', '47', '46', '73', '99', '52', '56', '23', '7',
       'C3', '49', '62', '54', 'A1', '88', '70', '42', '74', '20', '21',
       '4', '62', '2', '3', '49', '79', '13', 'F4', 'A9', '20', '19', '19', '23',
       '70', '83', '61', '80', '81', '66', '82', '63', '9', '6', 'F8'], dtype=object)
```

I have tried this method

```
def col_convert(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        try:
            array[i] = str(int(array[i]))
        except:
            next
    return array
```

However for 1 million elements, this solution are quite slow. Are there any way faster to handle this task?

Comment: Why do you use `split('.')`?

Comment: And why do you want a **num**py array of strings as a result? Would it not be better to have an array of **numbers**?

Comment: your proposed solution removes strings. You do not need to check for type.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Ah because I want to score them as a string, they can be considered as area code in my company (the area code includes both number and string)

Comment: Write a little function that takes on element, determines the `type`, and applies the necessary conversion, and returns that string.  Then just apply that to the whole array (or list) with a list comprehension.  There isn't a whole-array `numpy` function that will handle all the cases as you want.  For tasks like this an object dtype array is inferior to a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
z1 = np.array([str(i).split('.')[0] for i in z])
```

**UPDATE**: Per OP's edit to remove leading zeros:

```
z1 = np.array([str(i).lstrip('0').split('.')[0] for i in z])
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I have editted my post. I also want to convert the values which starts with 0 such as '07', '09', '06' into '7', '9', '6'

Comment: @Long_NgV Please find the edit on my post to cover 0s as well. Thank you.